# Getting probability from z-score on TI-83

Tags: probability, calculator

I'm able to use a $z$-table, but would like to be able to use my ti-$83+$ to get value. For example, $P(z \leq   2.5) = 0.9938$ , given $2.5$ I would like to get $0.9938$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume this is about the standard normal distribution. See for instance [this link](http://cfcc.edu/faculty/cmoore/TINormal.htm), which I found by googling "Texas instruments ti-83 plus normal distribution".

Comment: That link was helpful, it didn't really tell me how, but i was able to get an approximation by doing normalcdf(-1E99, 2.5), which is pretty much P(z <=2.5) = P(-infinity <= z <= 2.5). Thanks your link led me to the answer!

Comment: Did you try just `normalcdf(2.5)`? It might work.